# Time interval between commands esp8266

Tags: esp8266

I work with ESP8266 (ESP-01).
I have a situation when I send several commands to the chip.
Do I have to wait any time between commands?
What is the minimal time for it? 50 ms? 250 ms? 500 ms?

I use an AT-command firmware.
My init sequence is: ATE, AT+CWMODE_CUR, AT+CWJAP_CUR, AT+CIPSTAMAC_CUR.
It is used once at boot time (or when I found out a fatal error).
Further, I use the repetitive sequences like as: AT+CIPSTART, AT+CIPSEND.
I always wait for answer from module and always parse it.
But do I have to wait some time between parsing the answer and sending a next command?

Something like this:

```
...
send(cmd1);
parse(ans1);
delay(?); // is it necessary?
send(cmd2);
parse(ans2);
delay(?); // is it necessary?
...
```

Comment: we need to know: with AT firmware? how big of commands? which commands? is the sequence self-dependent?

Comment: **dandavis**, I have edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

I receive answers with interrupt, and make a flag high when answer is received, some answers come with delay and some come instantly, can check Rx packet received flag to see if answer ready to parse. 
You can find my work here
https://github.com/programmer131/esp8266ATServer